# Comparing Dynamic dates

Tags: jquery

How to compare the two dates from div element using jQuery?
If the div is like:

```
  <div class="col-sm-5 text-right date-time" data-from="2015/6/16 9:20:00" data-to="2015/6/16 10:20:00">
```

The from and to dates are dynamic. After comparing it should display greater date based on time.

Please help - I searched but every where dates were first initialized and then compared.

Comment: Must Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use `new Date(attributeValue)` and compare like integers. Check this link http://jsfiddle.net/b0ye90ps/

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.date-time');

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var from = elements[i].getAttribute('data-from');
    var to = elements[i].getAttribute('data-to');
    var bigger = to;
    if(new Date(from) > new Date(to)) {
       bigger = from; 
    }
    elements[i].innerHTML = bigger + ' --> Compared ' + from + ' vs ' + to + ';<br>';
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I got the answer from above code...but suppose if the output should be like 16-17 June 2015 and their time suppose 09:00 PM - 6:00 AM instead of displaying bigger date. To achieve this what modification needs to be done?

Comment: @Amit You have to parse the date and get month, year and time then display.

Comment: If you can give the example of that it would be a great help for me.